# MariaDB database replication fails with SQL_Errno 1062

Tags: mariadb, database-replication, rhel

I have set up a mariadb replication as per [these instructions](https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-install-wordpress-with-mariadb-in-ssl-replication.40/). Things are working well. Well, mostly working actually, that is. I keep coming up with errors similar to this.

> Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry '136-202' for key 'PRIMARY'' on
>   query. Default database: 's7data'. Query: 'INSERT INTO history (uid,
>   nid, timestamp) VALUES ('136', '202', '1446221969')'

and

> Last_SQL_Errno: 1062
>
> Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry
>   'links:main-menu:page:node/128/edit:en:1:1' for key 'PRIMARY'' on
>   query. Default database: 's7data'. Query: 'INSERT INTO cache_menu
>   (cid, serialized, created, expire, data) VALUES
>   ('links:main-menu:page:node/128/edit:en:1:1', '1', '1446222020', '0',
>   'a:4:{s:9:\"min_depth\";i:1;s:9:\"max_depth\";i:1;s:8:\"expanded\";a:1:{i:0;i:0;}s:12:\"active_trail\";a:1:{i:0;i:0;}}')'

As a stop gap, I've tried running

```
stop slave; SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter = 100; start slave;
```

Which works but the problem will eventually crop up again. Can I skip individual issues?

Comment: Can you please post the content of your my.ini

Comment: "100" Ouch!  Who knows what important stuff you are skipping!

Comment: By now you probably have a lot of differences between the Master and Slave.  Use pt-table-sync to fix the mess.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I upvoted your comment. You convinced me to re-import the master form `mysqldump`. This helped a bunch. // The 100 was just pure frustration, but I quickly turned course after reading your comment! Thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After re-importing the database dump from the Master

`mysql -u <rootuser> -p database-target < db.dump.sql`

On the master I did a `reset master` and on the slave I did the

`stop slave;
reset slave; 
change master to ....
start slave;`

And finally added the skip duplicates by adding this to the my.cnf file as explained by http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/13/mysql-skip-duplicate-replication-errors/

```
slave-skip-errors = 1062
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see why this was downvoted. The fact of the matter is MariaDB/MySQL replication can be a complete nighmare and error `1062` often appears. A common way to fix the problem is to do an entire reload. So I partly agree with this post.